# Linux: check if file descriptor is available for reading

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptor

Considering the following example, emulating a command which gives output after 10 seconds: `exec 5< <(sleep 10; pwd)`

In Solaris, if I check the file descriptor earlier than 10 seconds, I can see that it has a size of 0 and this tells me that it hasn't been populated with data yet. I can simply check every second until the file test condition is met (different from 0) and then pull the data:

```
while true; do
    if [[ -s /proc/$$/fd/5 ]]; then
        variable=$(cat <&5)
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

But in Linux I can't do this (RedHat, Debian etc). All file descriptors appear with a size of 64 bytes no matter if they hold data or not. For various commands that will take a variable amount of time to dump their output, I will not know when I should read the file descriptor. No, I don't want to just wait for `cat <&5` to finish, I need to know when I should perform the `cat` in the first place. Because I am using this mechanism to issue simultaneous commands and assign their output to corresponding file descriptors. As mentioned already, this works great in Solaris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the skeleton of an idea :

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 5< <(sleep 4; pwd)
while true
do
  if
    read -t 0 -u 5 dummy
  then
    echo Data available
    cat <&5
    break
  else
    echo No data
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

From the Bash reference manual :

> If timeout is 0, read returns immediately, without trying to read and
>   data. The exit status is 0 if input is available on the specified file
>   descriptor, non-zero otherwise.

The idea is to use read with `-t 0` (to have zero timeout) and `-u 5` (read from file descriptor 5) to instantly check for data availability.

Of course this is just a toy loop to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I knew about `read` being able to... read from a file descriptor but never thought about what would using `-t` would do. I eliminated the `dummy` variable since it will not be populated even if data is available and the syntax works without it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by User Fred using only bash builtins works fine, but is a tiny bit non-optimal due to polling for the state of a file descriptor. If calling another interpreter (for example Python) is not a no-go, a non-polling version is possible:

```
#! /bin/bash
(
    sleep 4
    echo "This is the data coming now"
    echo "More data"
) | (
    python3 -c 'import select;select.select([0],[],[])'
    echo "Data is now available and can be processed"
    # Replace with more sophisticated real-world processing, of course:
    cat
)
```

The single line `python3 -c 'import select;select.select([0],[],[])'` waits until STDIN has data ready. It uses the standard `select(2)` system call, for which I have not found a direct shell equivalent or wrapper.